# C# set/get shorthand Question

Tags: c#

I"m a little confused with this short hand. Does this allow me to acesss myVar and set myVar like so?

```
object.myVar = 5;
newNum = object.myVar;
```

I don't get this.

```
 private int myVar;

 public int MyProperty
 {
  get { return myVar; }
  set { myVar = value; }
 }
```

Comment: that's not shorthand for get/set. shorthand would be automatic properties. `public int MyProperty { get; set; }`.

Comment: In addition to others' answer, your code can't be compiled because `object` is not a valid variable name :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what this means is that you have a "hidden" private integer called `myVar` that nobody outside the class can see, but people from the outside can only see a property called `MyProperty`, that happens to redirect to `myVar`, but they won't know it !

from the inside, you can do :

```
this.myVar = 12;
int test = this.myVar; /*(this. would actually be optionnal)*/
```

from the outside, if `myInstance` is an instance of your class, people can do this :

```
int test = myInstance.MyProperty;
myInstance.MyProperty = 12;
```

The point of properties is to hide the private members, and control how they are accessed.

Answer (score 2):

It does not allow you, that is the point. You access the private variable via the public property.

Answer (score 1):

In version 3.0 and above you can also do:

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

And access them like so:

```
object.MyProperty = 5;
newNum = object.MyProperty;
```

Comment: Should be `object.MyProperty` not MyVar.

Answer (score 1):

No it won't be redundant

```
public int MyProperty { get; set;}
```

This creates a public and a private variable. 
Outside classes can command it but there is a hidden private variable that will use the get set method. This is still safe since it is the class itself that will change the values and not some other method from outside.

Answer (score 0):

No it allows you to access your variable myVar by using this:

```
object.MyProperty = 5;
newNum = object.MyProperty;
```

you could get rid of the backing variable entirely and do this though:

```
 public int MyProperty
 {
  get; set;
 }
```

which will still allow you to access your property like the first code section in my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

wouldn't this be redundant since if MyProperty is public it can already be 'get' and 'set'?